# Merge Raster Data Not Working

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I am trying to merge about 70+ raster images into 1 large raster tiff. I try running the tool located in raster>miscellaneous>merge and before running the tool, selecting all the images I'd like to have merged, and selecting a destination and output file name. I run the tool, and it only renders 1 of the rasters and cropped pieces of the 2 neighboring rasters. I am unsure as to why this is happening, is there any other way to merge multiple rasters, or a fix to this problem?

Comment: Did you use the tool as in this tutorial https://opensourceoptions.com/merge-multiple-rasters-in-qgis-create-a-raster-mosaic/?

Comment: yes, I did, I used that tool and watched the YouTube video associated with it found here: https://youtu.be/ARm202TS1eE

Comment: Does the tool work for less images? Can you see all the images that you want to merge correctly in the QGIS project, side by side?

Comment: it does work with less images technically, though after it is merged, it messes with the colors, and the originally transparent background becomes a black background.

Comment: You could try `gdal_merge` on the command line

Comment: It feels like we must get more information about your source images.